# Splitting string using boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, split

Is it a good idea? For a reason I thought it should be faster than boost's tokenizer or split. however most of the time I'm stuck in the boost::spirit::compile

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct ValueList : bsq::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>()>
{
    ValueList(const std::string& sep, bool isCaseSensitive) : ValueList::base_type(query)
    {
        if(isCaseSensitive)
        {
            query = value >> *(sep >> value);
            value = *(bsq::char_ - sep);
        }
        else
        {
            auto separator = bsq::no_case[sep];
            query = value >> *(separator >> value);
            value = *(bsq::char_ - separator);
        }
    }
    bsq::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>()> query;
    bsq::rule<Iterator, std::string()> value;
};

inline bool Split(std::vector<std::string>& result, const std::string& buffer, const std::string& separator,
                  bool isCaseSensitive)
{
    result.clear();
    ValueList<std::string::const_iterator> parser(separator, isCaseSensitive);
    auto itBeg = buffer.begin();
    auto itEnd = buffer.end();
    if(!(bsq::parse(itBeg, itEnd, parser, result) && (itBeg == itEnd)))
        result.push_back(buffer);
    return true;
}
```

I've implemented it as shown above. What is wrong with my code? or just because the separator is defined in runtime the recompilation is inevitable?

EDIT001:
Example and comparison with possible implementation with boost::split and original imp with tokenizer on [CoLiRu](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9af60ee8bb7ead5)
Looks like coliru is down now. In any case these are result for 1M runs on string "2lkhj309|ioperwkl|20sdf39i|rjjdsf|klsdjf230o|kx23904iep2|xp39f4p2|xlmq2i3219" with separator "|"

> 8000000 splits in 1081ms.
> 8000000 splits in 1169ms.
> 8000000
> splits in 2663ms.

first is for tokenizer, second is for boost::split and the third is for boost::spirit

Comment: ``query = value >> *(sep >> value);`` Will not parse for an empty string. Do you want that?

Comment: empty string => empty vector which is fine

Comment: Can you share the benchmark code + data?

Comment: will do, the code is exactly one I use, as for data have to retrieve it

Comment: Well, your code doesn't even show what (kind of) delimiters you call it with. So, the code is not there either :S

Comment: Done. It is general purpose function, take any delimiter you wish. In this particular case it was a pipe. but it can be ampersand or semicolon as well.

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg thanks. For future reference, remember to `@address` users in comments, or they won't get updates

Comment: I usually do, didnt know it notifies user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the different versions do not do the same thing:

- in particular token compression behaves differently (I fixed it for `boost::split` but it doesn't appear to be a feature for `boost::tokenizer`)
- separators were treated as string literals rather than charsets in the Spirit version (fixed that)

Yes, recompiles are inevitable with dynamic separators. But no, this is not the bottleneck (the other approaches have dynamic separators too):

---

I've done some optimizations. The timings:

- [Coliru clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3311e67fb11341be):

  ```
  8000000 original (boost::tokenizer) rate: 2.84257μs
  10000000 possible (boost::split) rate: 3.09941μs
  10000000 spirit (dynamic version) rate: 1.45456μs
  10000000 spirit (direct version, avoid type erasure) rate: 1.25588μs

  next step:
  10000000 spirit (precompiled sep) rate: 1.18059μs
  ```
- [Coliru g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a21cafe08dbbe9b)

  ```
  8000000 original (boost::tokenizer) rate: 2.92805μs
  10000000 possible (boost::split) rate: 2.75442μs
  10000000 spirit (dynamic version) rate: 1.32821μs
  10000000 spirit (direct version, avoid type erasure) rate: 1.10712μs

  next step:
  10000000 spirit (precompiled sep) rate: 1.0791μs
  ```
- Local system g++:

  ```
  sehe@desktop:/tmp$ time ./test
  8000000 original (boost::tokenizer) rate: 1.80061μs
  10000000 possible (boost::split) rate: 1.29754μs
  10000000 spirit (dynamic version) rate: 0.607789μs
  10000000 spirit (direct version, avoid type erasure) rate: 0.488087μs

  next step:
  10000000 spirit (precompiled sep) rate: 0.498769μs
  ```

As you can see the Spirit approach doesn't need to be slower. What steps did I take? http://paste.ubuntu.com/11001344/

- refactor benchmark to display rate (no change) **3.523μs**
- made case_insensitivity choice of caller (just use `no_case[char_(delimiter)]` if required) **2.742μs.**
- eliminate `value` subrule (reduced copying and dynamic dispatch because of type-erased non-terminal rule) **2.579μs.**
- Made delimiter charset instead of string literal: **2.693μs.**

  > see [intermediate version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94915a30582b7870) on coliru. *(I recommend the code below, it's much more cleaned up)*
- Using qi::raw[] instead of std::string synthesized attributes (avoid copying!) **0.624072μs**
- Eliminating all non-terminals (i.e. type-erasure; see `spirit_direct` implementation) rate: **0.491011μs**

Now it seems fairly obvious that all the implementations would benefit from not "compiling" the separator each time. I didn't do it for all the approaches, but for fun let's do it for the Spirit version:

- Using hardcoded '|' delimiter **0.455269μs** // fixed delimiter

---

#### Full listing:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3311e67fb11341be)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

void original(std::vector<std::string>& result, const std::string& input, const std::string& delimiter)
{
    result.clear();
    boost::char_separator<char> sep(delimiter.c_str());
    boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char>, std::string::const_iterator, std::string> tok(input, sep);

    for (const auto& token : tok)
    {
        result.push_back(token);
    }
}

void possible(std::vector<std::string>& result, const std::string& input, const std::string& delimiter)
{
    result.clear();
    boost::split(result, input, boost::is_any_of(delimiter), boost::algorithm::token_compress_off);
}

namespace bsq = boost::spirit::qi;

void spirit_direct(std::vector<std::string>& result, const std::string& input, char const* delimiter)
{
    result.clear();
    using namespace bsq;
    if (!parse(input.begin(), input.end(), raw[*(char_ - char_(delimiter))] % char_(delimiter), result))
        result.push_back(input);
}

namespace detail {
    template <typename Sep> bsq::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::vector<std::string>()>
        make_spirit_parser(Sep const& sep) 
        {
            using namespace bsq;
            return raw[*(char_ - sep)] % sep;
        }

    static const auto precompiled_pipes = make_spirit_parser('|');
}

void spirit(std::vector<std::string>& result, const std::string& input, char const* delimiter)
{
    result.clear();
    if (!bsq::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), detail::make_spirit_parser(bsq::char_(delimiter)), result))
        result.push_back(input);
}

void spirit_pipes(std::vector<std::string>& result, const std::string& input)
{
    result.clear();
    if (!bsq::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), detail::precompiled_pipes, result))
        result.push_back(input);
}

template <typename F> void bench(std::string const& caption, F approach) {
    size_t const iterations = 1000000;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using C = high_resolution_clock;

    auto start = C::now();

    size_t count = 0;
    for (auto i = 0U; i < iterations; ++i) {
        count += approach();
    }

    auto us = duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(C::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << count << " " << caption << " rate: " << (1.*us/iterations) << "μs\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::string const input = "2309|ioperwkl|2039i|rjjdsf|klsdjf230o|kx23904iep2|xp,39,4p2|xlmq2i3219||";
    auto separator = "|";

    std::vector<std::string> result;

    bench("original (boost::tokenizer)", [&] {
            original(result, input, separator);
            return result.size();
        });
    bench("possible (boost::split)", [&] {
            possible(result, input, separator);
            return result.size();
        });
    bench("spirit (dynamic version)", [&] {
            spirit(result, input, separator);
            return result.size();
        });
    bench("spirit (direct version, avoid type erasure)", [&] {
            spirit_direct(result, input, separator);
            return result.size();
        });

    std::cout << "\nnext step:\n";
    bench("spirit (precompiled sep)", [&] {
            spirit_pipes(result, input);
            return result.size();
        });
}
```

Comment: I've added one intermediate version that I kept around, for comparison (it still had the case-sensitivity switch). Note the code in general has been cleaned up a bit, making it significantly shorter.

Comment: Awesome as usual. Interestingly the split is faster than tokenizer for gcc but slower for clang and msvc

Comment: so the part that made big difference was - use raw (dont copy) and remove non-terminals. What are these non-terminals?

Comment: Newer versions of gcc make the tokenizer considerably faster. Perhaps it's a modern optimization

Comment: Non terminals: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html

Comment: so in general we are talking about rule and grammar right? so is it a bad idea to use both of these? Since, IMHO, I always can replace these above with direct approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77237/discussion-between-sehe-and-kreuzerkrieg).