# Specify a charset without intepreting ranges

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I'm quite puzzled with parsing strings when I have to define in rule the minus and it is just a minus character and not a range of characters between two endpoints.

For example, when you write a rule to percent encode a string of characters you normally would write

```
*(bk::char_("a-zA-Z0-9-_.~") | '%' << bk::right_align(2, 0)[bk::upper[bk::hex]]);
```

Which normally means "letters, capital letters, digits, minus sign, underscore, dot and tilde", but the third minus sign would create a range between 9 and underscore or something, so you have to put the minus at the end `bk::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_.~-")`.

It solves current problem but what would one do when the input is dynamic, like user input, and minus sign just means minus character?

How do I prevent from Spirit assign a special meaning to any of possible characters?

EDIT001:
I resort to more concrete example from @sehe [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046512/splitting-string-using-boost-spirit)

```
void spirit_direct(std::vector<std::string>& result, const std::string& input, char const* delimiter)
{
    result.clear();
    using namespace bsq;
    if(!parse(input.begin(), input.end(), raw[*(char_ - char_(delimiter))] % char_(delimiter), result))
        result.push_back(input);
}
```

in case you want to ensure the minus is treated as minus and not a range one would to alter the code as following (according to @sehe proposal below).

```
void spirit_direct(std::vector<std::string>& result, const std::string&
    input, char const* delimiter)
{
    result.clear();
    bsq::symbols<char, bsq::unused_type> sym_;
    std::string separators = delimiter;
    for(auto ch : separators)
    {
        sym_.add(std::string(1, ch));
    }
    using namespace bsq;
    if(!parse(input.begin(), input.end(), raw[*(char_ - sym_)] % sym_, result))
        result.push_back(input);
}
```

Which looks quite elegant.
In case of using static constant rule I guess I can escape characters with '\', square brackets were meant as one of those "special" characters which need to be escaped. Why? what is the meaning of []? Is there any additional characters to escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.

You devise and specify the supported patterns that the user can supply with their meanings.

Next,

- you write the code that transforms it into a character-set (e.g. expand all ranges (if supported in user input) and sort the `-` to be the first character by definition).
- do not use a character set at all.

  - why not use `char_ [ _pass = my_match_predicate(_1) ]`
  - why not just make an alternation of literal characters? `lit('a') | 'b' | '-' | '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'`
  - why not use `qi::symbols<char, char>` (or even `qi::symbols<char, qi::unused_type> sym_;` with `raw [ sym_ ]` or similar)

    > **Update** The `qi::symbols<>` approach is surprisingly fast: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81a85f4c3b8fc610). I had a recent optimization job where it disappointed: see this answer (under "Spirit (Trie)") – [Binary String to Hex c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210120/binary-string-to-hex-c/29214966#29214966)

In general, I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but Spirit is *not* well-suited for generating rules on the fly. See some of my existing [boost-spirit](/questions/tagged/boost-spirit) answers on this site.

Comment: ho-ho, you have a lot :) lets looks at your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046512/splitting-string-using-boost-spirit consider the "delimiter" is ",|-~" then it will capture 4 delimiters (',','|','}','~') when the average Joe meant 4 delimiters too but ',','|','-','~'. I cannot specify the pattern for input its too "far away" and it should be backward compatible (minus just means minus). As for next points - 1) not elegant. 2a) looks cumbersome, but maybe I didnt get it. 2b) much better but again not a top of elegance. 2c) looks like just what the doctor ordered

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg "it should be backward compatible" - see, there's your specification! And about the linked answer... [what's wrong with a simple ordering](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b21fd6d120e393c)?

Comment: thats it, it is not MY specification... long story... The ordering stuff - the good one, it is nice and ugly :) IMHO, the symbols<> stuff is more readable and easier to understanding

Comment: odd stuff, when I mention a user with "@" it just disappears from the comment

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg OT but that's because you're addressing the author of the post (Q or A) and nobody else was involved in the comment thread. Kinda violates [Principle Of Least Surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) but oh well :)

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg `qi::symbols` may be nice, but the charsets (char_) will compile down to significantly faster parsers, Don't forget your original goal :) Of course, you can do the preprocessing on the `delim` parameter once: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa4ce5d1972d2d78)**

Comment: Actually... strike that. The `qi::symbols<>` approach is surprisingly fast: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81a85f4c3b8fc610)**. I had a recent optimization job where it disappointed: [see this answer (under "Spirit (Trie)"))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29210120/binary-string-to-hex-c/29214966#29214966)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use \- `bk::char_("a-zA-Z0-9\\-_.~")`?

Comment: nope since I'm looking for something like a directive which disables special character meaning

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg it doesn't exist.